# Updating a UITableView on Firebase Data Change

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I am trying to have table cells that auto refresh when any other of the cells are changed. I hoped that my code could find the object within the table array, change a value, and refresh the table view all in one fell swoop, but for some reason, even though my array updates, the table refuses to instantly update. To see my new values I have to restart the app or reopen the View.

This is what I am doing so far:

```
usersRef.queryOrdered(byChild "contactList/(currentUID!)").queryEqual(toValue: true).observe(.childChanged, with: { (snapshot) in
if let friends = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

            //Making a new updated contact

            let name = friends["name"] as! String
            print(name)
            let edit = Contact()
            edit.name = name;
            edit.isSafe = friends["isSafe"] as! Bool
            edit.email = friends["email"] as! String

            //My manager object has a custom array objects called contacts. 
            self.manager.index(withName: name, contact: edit)
            self.tableView.reloadData();
        } else {
            print("Failed to Convert")
        }
    })

}
```

index(withName: String, contact: Contact) method in the ContactManager:

```
//This method goes through the contactList to check names to see which contact has a specific name equal to "name", then it uses the "contact" to update that specific child.

    public mutating func index(withName: String, contact: Contact) {
    for iterator in 0 ..< contactList.count {
        if (contactList[iterator].name == withName) {
            contactList[iterator] = contact
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `self.tableView.reloadData();` should be called in the main thread

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem. Your calling `self.tableView.reloadData()` in the background thread. All UI changes need to be made on the main thread. like this.

```
  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData();
  }
```